# How validate query params in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, nestjs

Yo, i have store application with nestjs, i need validate mongo id, which is pass by query, the problem is that i also pass and search query. I write pipe which validate all values, and exclude this search query

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidationObjectId implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: UniqueId, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
        if (
            !Types.ObjectId.isValid(value) &&
            metadata.data !== "searchString"
        ) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Неверный параметр запроса");
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

But this code not reusable for other case. I want get some examples, how i can do this

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The cleanest and most reusable approach would probably be to make use of the `ValidationPipe` with a Query-DTO-Class.

Take a look at the following example.

https://gitlab.com/WaldemarLehner/nestjs-swagger-example/-/tree/1aea48597ddcf93b0a0d1449fe5087413415bbee

Inside the [Controller](https://gitlab.com/WaldemarLehner/nestjs-swagger-example/-/blob/25a4d18f33cff92b759c210f868e318c0dd6df74/src/app.controller.ts#L77-81) you can pass a Pipe to the `@Query()`-Decorator.
You can use the `ValidationPipe` which already comes with Nest and makes use of the `class-validator` and `class-transformer` Packages.

You can create a DTO-Class for your Query-Parameters as done in the [PostHelloQuery.dto.ts](https://gitlab.com/WaldemarLehner/nestjs-swagger-example/-/blob/25a4d18f33cff92b759c210f868e318c0dd6df74/src/dto/PostHelloQuery.dto.ts) from my example.

```
import { IsBoolean, IsOptional } from "class-validator";

export class PostHelloQueryDTO {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsBoolean()
    public useExclamation?: boolean;
}
```

Here you define constraints for your Data using decorators from `class-validator`. For a list of all decorators, please refer to https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators .

If none of the validators fit your needs you can also create your own Decorator as shown [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators).

In my example, the `useExclamation`-Query Param is an optional boolean.
Note that incoming query parameters are parsed as strings.

The conversion is done using the `enableInplicitConversion`-Option as seen in the Controller:

```
@Query(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: {enableImplicitConversion: true},
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true
})) query: PostHelloQueryDTO
```

For more information about using `ValidationPipe` with `class-validator`, you can take a look at the NestJS Documentation:

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

For your specific Use-Case (Validating MongoDB IDs), I have found an open Issue with an Example Implementation for a `@IsMongoDB`-Decorator:

https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/630#issuecomment-645638436

Comment: Great answer. But how we can validate nested request query and transform it like if I send query this way: 
```/user?id[gte]=12```
And get query object like this:
```{ id: { gte: '12' } }```

Comment: @AmeerHamza use the combination of `@Type` from `class-transformer` (https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects) and `@ValidateNested` from `class-validator` (https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-nested-objects). Otherwise, everything is the same.

Comment: For me, the transformation logic, with the same config as the answer did not work. so I added a manual transformation `@Transform((value: string) => Number(value))` on the property

Answer (score 2):

For single query param usage, you can play with this example:

```
import { ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';

type TOptional<T> = T | undefined;

@Injectable()
export class ValidateEnum<T extends Record<string, unknown>> implements PipeTransform<T> {
    constructor(public readonly enumObj: T, public readonly isRequired = false) {}

    async transform(value: TOptional<T>, { data: argName }: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<TOptional<T>> {
        const withValidation = this.isRequired ? true : value !== undefined;
        if (withValidation) {
            const enumValues = Object.values(this.enumObj);
            if (!enumValues.includes(value)) {
                throw new BadRequestException(`Invalid ${argName}=${value} - possible values: ${enumValues.join('|')}`);
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

If you want to use a pipe with a DTO object, check this out:

```
import { ArgumentMetadata, Injectable, PipeTransform } from '@nestjs/common';
import { plainToInstance, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { IsInt, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';

export class PaginationRequestDto {
    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    @IsOptional()
    public readonly page?: number;

    @Type(() => Number)
    @IsInt()
    @IsOptional()
    public readonly take?: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class PaginationTransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
    async transform(dto: PaginationRequestDto, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
        if (!metatype) {
            return dto;
        }

        return plainToInstance(metatype, dto);
    }
}
```

And usage example:

```
@Get('')
// @UsePipes(new PaginationTransformPipe()) // also possible
public async someOperation(
    @Query(new PaginationTransformPipe()) pagination: PaginationRequestDto,
    @Query('status', new ValidateEnum(ESomeEnum)) status?: ESomeEnum
    ) {
    // ...your logic
}
```

> For someone, it can be helpful to use [default pipes](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/packages/common/pipes)