# NestJS ValidationPipe is not working properly for @Query()

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, dto

I'm trying to transform some query params from string to int using the in-build NestJS ValidationPipe, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly,

Here is my controller :

```
import {
..., ValidationPipe
} from '@nestjs/common';

...

@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get()
findAll(@Req() req, @Query(new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
})) query: GetTestDto) {
    return this.testService.findAll(query, req.user.id);
}
```

Here is my DTO :

```
import { IsInt, IsOptional, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class GetTestDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsString()
    public search: string;

    @IsOptional()
    @Transform(({value}) => {
        console.log(typeof value); // => string / I'm just testing here
        return value
    })
    @IsInt()
    public page: number;

    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    public limit: number;
}
```

main.ts :

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
    await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

when I try to call `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/test?page=1&limit=10` I get this

```
validation error from the DTO I think:
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "page must be an integer number",
        "limit must be an integer number"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I've tried deleting node_modules and dist folders, but nothing changed.
I don't want to use @Transform() in the DTO as a solution, I would prefer for the pipe to do the changing with the `enableImplicitConversion: true`

Can I please get some help?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Pass the ValidationPipe options in the `main.ts` file

```js
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
      whitelist: true,
    })
  );
```

2. Get rid of the `@Transform` decorator in your dto class.
3. Get rid of the ValidationPipe passed to the `@Query` decorator in your controller

```js
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Get()
findAll(@Req() req, @Query() query: GetTestDto) {
    return this.testService.findAll(query, req.user.id);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the error I was getting comes from the global validation pipe, in which I didn't enable transform and implicit conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Query (`@Query()`) and URL (`@Param()`) parameters always come in as strings. To force them to resolve to numbers you can add `@Type(() => Number)` so that `class-transformer` turns them into a number and `class-validator` then reads the correct value

Comment: If I use the `@Type(() => Number)` approach, I won't be needing the `ValidationPipe()` in the `@Query()` with the `{ enableImplicitConversion: true }` though, no? instead of setting up the conversion in the DTO explicitly, I want the inbuilt NestJS ValidationPipe to do it for me. by the way, I'm following this guy's answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225539/how-validate-query-params-in-nestjs)